# Sticky menu with options marked

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll, sticky

I'm having many problems with an idea I'm trying to do. I have a web with an smooth vertical scrolling and I need a menu on the left which marks in which section I am.

So the ideal thing would be to make this menu change depending on the point I pass by the scrollbar. Please some of you has any idea?

I've already got to make this menu appears in an specific point of the scrollball cause at first I dont want any menu at all.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I know of at least two jQuery plugins that do the same thing...

- [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)
- [visualNav](https://github.com/Mottie/visualNav) - plugin I wrote, but not nearly as fancy as Waypoints.

Edit: updated Waypoints link to show one of the better demos.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second one plugin is brilliant, it's what I needed it but I have still a problem cause I need that the menu appears in a concret point of the page because at firt I have a starting page where there's no menu. the problem is that I'm trying to do with 2 js but there must be some kind of problem among the different js

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Different js? You mean the difference between jQuery and javascript? - jQuery is a library of javascript, if that is what you mean. As for the menu placement of visualNav, it's all in the CSS.